# How to write (La)TeX (with parentheses) [or any other TeX-related logo]

Tags: macros, logos

I'm looking after a macro to write the (La)TeX logo (with parentheses), i.e. something similar to `\TeX`, `\LaTeX`, but where the output includes ()'s.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Stupid question: What is the LaTeX logo (as opposed to the result of `\LaTeX`)?

Comment: I think he wants a macro which writes "(La)TeX" in the same style like `\TeX` or `\LaTeX`.

Comment: If you want to have it output `(L_A)T_EX` with the braces (as in Martin's answer), could you please make your question clearer. I read it as the “TeX logo and LaTeX logo”.

Comment: It's usually referred to as `\AllTeX`

Comment: But `\AllTeX` would include e.g. ConTeXt, woudn't it, while (La)TeX means `LaTeX and/or TeX`.

Comment: @Martin. `\AllTeX` is used by _TUGBoat_ to mean 'all TeX formats', as I understand it, and typesets '(La)TeX)'.

Comment: Thanks, @Joseph, where is it defined?

Comment: @Martin. `tugboat` package by Robin Fairbairns

Comment: @user13225 That's a separate question, but all you seem to want is `\TeX`.

Comment: Out of curiosity... Is the general term (La)TeX frowned upon like C/C++?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{dtk-logos}% or use package holog

\begin{document}
\Large
\XeTeX    \\ \XeLaTeX  \\
\AmS      \\ \AmSLaTeX \\
\AMSLaTeX \\ \AmSTeX   \\
\AMSTEX   \\ \AMSTeX   \\
\BibTeX   \\ \LAMSTeX  \\
\LamSTeX  \\ \La       \\
\LaTeX    \\ \LaTeXTeX \\
\MF       \\ \MFun     \\
\MP       \\ \SLITEX   \\
\SLiTeX   
\newpage
\MakeIndex\\ \emTeX    \\
\PubliCTeX\\ \TeXXeT   \\
\TeXeT    \\ \WinEdt   \\
\LyX      \\ \exTeX    \\
\LaTeXe   \\ \PS       \\
\PiC      \\ \PiCTeX   \\
\NTS      \\ \eTeX     \\
\ExTeX    \\ \DANTE    \\
\ConTeXt  \\ \MiKTeX   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just saw, that I have a bug for METAFUN ...

---

Here a second image which shows the commands and output side by side to make them easier to find. (Added by Martin Scharrer)

[image]

Comment: The TeX--XeT logo is wrong! It's supposed to have the second half in a flipped font (`xbmc10`), which is unfortunately not (yet) available as a well-hinted Type1 font. I intend to rectify this at some point, having armed myself with the Type 1 spec and the METAFONTbook. I believe this plan would work: (1) write some METAFONT code to output enough information (`(l+r)/2` with an appropriate mode?) to locate the appropriate axis about which to flip each character in the AMS' `CMBX10` Type1 font (2) write e.g. a fontforge script to actually flip the glyphs about these axes.

Comment: Oh, and I guess either someone has to add "U" to the "logo" family, or the METAFUN logo has to be in a different font? (The METAFUN manual appears to set it in `\textrm` at the moment; this is not particularly easy on my eyes.)

Comment: What about LuaTex and LuaLaTex?

Comment: What about iTeX?!

Comment: I'm missing a "Xe(La)TeX". Is there the "Xe" on its own?

Comment: @Richard: You forgot its bell jingle. :)

Comment: @Herbet: How to fix the `MFun` control sequence? If that is not what SamB is talking about already.

Comment: [A forgotten logo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2099/xport).

Comment: @xport: LOL, and you should wrap it in an `\mbox` to keep the font change local and also enter horizontal mode.

Comment: @Martin: I have not read TeXBook. :-)

Comment: With this code example, by `\DANTE` I got the result of @MartinScharrer in caps, but not the one seen in the first picture.

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz: Do you have the dante font installed?

Comment: @Herbert: I guess not. Is it available on CTAN? A first glance did not show it to me. However, I would expect a warning instead of silently using a different font.

Comment: Btw. the background: I just took a long text I wrote for the Web with a lot of TeX, LaTeX words in the body text, replacing all occurrences of logos using `xesearch` by  `\SearchList{logos}{\csname#1\endcsname}{TeX,LaTeX,eTeX,XeTeX,XeLaTeX,LuaTeX,LuaLaTeX,ConTeXt,DANTE,AMS,...}` and `\SearchList{acronyms}{\textsc{#1}}{TUG,CTAN,...}`.

Comment: @Herbert -- the "meta" logos are set with the font `logo<size>`, which contains only the letters necessary for "METAFONT" and "METAPOST".  no "U" (and no lowercase either).  the original "MF" logo was set with `manfnt`, and that didn't have "P" or "S", so someone (i've forgotten who) extracted the logo letters and created the `logo` fonts.  an extended `logo` font could be created with the "U", but as far as i know, no one has done so yet.  you might suggest it to taco.

Comment: @Herbert -- i just noticed -- the height of the "A" in `\La` is not good; it should be the same as its height in "(La)TeX)".

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: `\providecommand\TeXLive{\TeX{}Live}`

Comment: Currently the `dtklogos` packages does not work anymore when compiling with `lualatex`: `fontspec` complains that it cannot find the font `DANTE`.

Comment: you need an open type version of the DANTE font.

Comment: @Herbert: That doesn't seem to be on ctan?

Comment: It seems almost all the logo macros have been removed in recent versions of `dtklogos`.  I am using 2014/11/15 v2.2 and almost every logo in this answer's sample document fails with an "Undefined control sequence" error.

Comment: @Caramdir the `dtklogos` is obsolete nowadays.  Please use `dtk-logos` instead.

Answer (score 31):

The [hologo](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hologo) package provides a long list of TeX related logos. They are used with `\hologo{<name>}` where `<name>` is the name of the respective logo:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage{longtable,array}

\begin{document}

Usage: \verb=\hologo{<name>}=

Example: \verb=\hologo{(La)TeX}= \hologo{(La)TeX}

Table of all possible names:

\def\hologoEntry#1#2#3{%
  #1&#2&\hologoLogoSetup{#1}{variant=#2}\hologo{#1}&#3\tabularnewline
}
\begin{longtable}{>{\ttfamily}l>{\ttfamily}lll}
  \rmfamily\bfseries{name} & \rmfamily\bfseries variant
  & \bfseries logo & \bfseries since\\
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hologoList
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The following picture shows the available names for `\hologo` (the document produced with the code above):

[image]

Comment: I got errors using the `doc` and `gmutils` packages, but this did it for me! Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: What about their boldface version?

Answer (score 19):

I coded the following macro based on the normal `\LaTeX` macro for the documentation of my new `adjustbox` package. The `\textorpdfstring` needs `hyperref` and is to ensure that it works in sectioning commands.

```
\def\LATeX{\texorpdfstring{(L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em)\kern -.075em\TeX}{(La)TeX}}
```

without `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\def\LATeX{(L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em)\kern -.075em\TeX}
```