# How can I see the "implementation" of protected commands such as \LaTeX?

Tags: macros, sourcecode

After reading another question relating to how to see definitions of commands, I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\show\LaTeX
\end{document}
```

But this shows me in my logfile:

```
\LaTeX=macro:
\protect \LaTeX
```

I just want to see where the `\LaTeX` command deep down somewhere finally says "OK, make the 'L' big, then make a little raised 'a,' then ..."

Comment: See also the related question [Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined). I don't think it is a direct duplicate, because the current question is about a specific case of macros where `\show` alone doesn't work.

Comment: Also related to `\LaTeX`: [How to write (La)TeX (with braces) or any other TeX-related logo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-braces-or-any-other-tex-related-logo)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Some macros are defined to be robust by expanding to `\protect` followed by a macro with almost the same name but ending with a space! Special care must be taken to define and use such macros because spaces are normally not allowed in macro names. If such a macro is written into external files (`.aux`, `.toc`, ...) the space is not taken as part of the macro name any longer, so that the original macro is called again.

To see the definitions of such macros you need to use the following code:

```
\expandafter\show\csname LaTeX \endcsname
```

The `\csname <text>\endcsname` can be used to build a macro called `\<text>` which can include non-letters like numbers or spaces. The `\expandafter` is required to expand `\csname LaTeX \endcsname` (note the space after the `X`) to `\LaTeX`  (also note the space here) before `\show` is executed.

I also programmed a command line tool called [`texdef`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texdef) to display such definitions:

```
 texdef -t latex LaTeX
```

(Instead of `texdef -t latex` you can also write `latexdef` if that name was installed)

This will display the definition of `\LaTeX` and detect that it calls `\LaTeX`  and also shows the definition of it.

```
$ texdef -t latex LaTeX

\LaTeX:
macro:->\protect \LaTeX  


\LaTeX :
\long macro:->L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX
```

Alternatively use quotes to add the space explicitly:

```
 texdef -t latex 'LaTeX '
```

Comment: Very neat, thanks! Efficient how the LaTeX symbol uses the TeX symbol in its definition, too.

Answer (score 52):

An alternative to Martin's answer to to redefine `\protect`:

```
\begingroup
  \let\protect\show
  \LaTeX
\endgroup
```

(The group is not compulsory, but means that you can keep going with a document and not have everything go wrong. If you are just making a short 'test' document, you can miss it out.)

Answer (score 39):

Besides Martin's solution, there is a `show2e` package that I often use:

```
% \usepackage{show2e}
\showcmd\LaTeX
```

When compiling, it first gets

```
> \LaTeX=macro:
->\protect \LaTeX  .
```

And then

```
> \LaTeX =\long macro:
->L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize
\sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX .
<argument> \LaTeX
```

Comment: I keep getting surprised by packages I never knew existed. Thanks for introducing it to me.

Answer (score 16):

With the package `xpatch` (or the experimental `regexpatch`) one can say

```
\xshowcmd\LaTeX
```

and get the answer

```
> \LaTeX =\long macro:
->L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize 
\sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX .
```

The command will also show the meaning of macros defined with `\newcommand` to have an optional argument. So, after `\newcommand{\foo}[1][bar]{#1}`, with `\show\foo` one would get

```
> \foo=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \foo \\foo {bar}.
```

but with `\xshowcmd\foo` the answer would be

```
> \\foo=\long macro:
[#1]->#1.
```

As you can see, the implementation of a robust command uses a command with a space in its name; a command with an optional argument uses another with a backslash in its name. Things can go even worse if you consider robust commands with an optional argument. The packages also cover `\newrobustcmd` from `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 8):

There is a program [`texdef`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef) that allows this, as **Martin** mentions in his answer.

I would just add that when our friend [**Psmith**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/psmith-the-friendly-tex-bot-at-your-service) is present in the [community chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), you can run `texdef` by posting a message in the chat of the following format:

```
!!/texdef -t latex -p multicol multicols
```

(This command will show the definition of `multicols` environment from the package [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol).)