# Custom LaTeX logo

Tags: macros, fontsize

I'm trying to get this "logo"

[image: My Logo, using hspace and raisebox]

At the moment I use the following command

```
\mbox{%
  M\hspace{-0.25ex}%
  \raisebox{0.18ex}{\tiny A}\hspace{-0.65ex}%
  T\hspace{-0.65ex}%
  \raisebox{0.18ex}{\tiny E}\hspace{-0.4ex}%
  X%
}
```

But does not fit when I change the font size as '\TeX' or '\LaTeX'. I tried to modify this code, but I can not find the necessary changes

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MaTeX}{%
  M\kern-.09em %
  {%
    \setbox0\hbox{T}%
    \vbox to\ht0{%
      \hbox{%
        \csname S@\f@size\endcsname
        \fontsize\sf@size\z@
        \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
        A%
      }%
      \vss
    }%
  }
  \kern-.40em
  \hbox{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125ex X}}
\makeatother
```

and this (modification)
[image: Fake version]

Comment: I don't know if you've already seen this (from your attempt it looks like you may have), but this may be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17888/12774

Comment: Just a note: it might be better to use `em` for the horizontal spacing, since it measures the "width" of the font, whereas `ex` measures its height. (Actually, `em` refers to the width of `M` and `ex` refers to the height of `x`.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is an attempt at creating something that stretches with the font size:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\aMaTeX}{%
  M\kern-.09em {\setbox0\hbox{T}%
    \vbox to\ht0{\hbox{%
      \csname S@\f@size\endcsname\fontsize\sf@size\z@ \math@fontsfalse\selectfont A}%
      \vss}%
    }\kern-.40em \hbox{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125ex X}}
\newcommand{\bMaTeX}{\mbox{%
  M\hspace{-0.25ex}%
  \raisebox{0.18ex}{\tiny A}\hspace{-0.65ex}%
  T\hspace{-0.65ex}%
  \raisebox{0.18ex}{\tiny E}\hspace{-0.4ex}%
  X%
}}
\newsavebox{\MaTeXbox}
\savebox{\MaTeXbox}{\normalsize%
    M\hspace{-0.25ex}%
    \raisebox{0.18ex}{\tiny A}\hspace{-0.65ex}%
    T\hspace{-0.65ex}%
    \raisebox{0.18ex}{\tiny E}\hspace{-0.4ex}%
    X%
  }%
\newcommand{\cMaTeX}{%
  \settoheight{\@tempdima}{M}%
  \resizebox{!}{\@tempdima}{\usebox{\MaTeXbox}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
  Original 1 & Original 2 & New & \verb|\TeX| & \verb|\LaTeX| \\
  \hline
  \footnotesize\aMaTeX & \footnotesize\bMaTeX & \footnotesize\cMaTeX & \footnotesize\TeX & \footnotesize\LaTeX \\
  \small\aMaTeX & \small\bMaTeX & \small\cMaTeX & \small\TeX & \small\LaTeX \\
  \aMaTeX & \bMaTeX & \cMaTeX & \TeX & \LaTeX \\
  \large\aMaTeX & \large\bMaTeX & \large\cMaTeX & \large\TeX & \large\LaTeX \\
  \Large\aMaTeX & \Large\bMaTeX & \Large\cMaTeX & \Large\TeX & \Large\LaTeX \\
  \LARGE\aMaTeX & \LARGE\bMaTeX & \LARGE\cMaTeX & \LARGE\TeX & \LARGE\LaTeX \\
  \Huge\aMaTeX & \Huge\bMaTeX & \Huge\cMaTeX & \Huge\TeX & \Huge\LaTeX
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In the above MWE, `\cMaTeX` stores a `\normalsize` version of MaTeX in a box, and resizes the box based on the height of `M` in the prevailing font. Resizing (while maintaining aspect ratio) is done using `\resizebox{!}{<height>}{<stuff>}` from the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

Comment: @PabloGonzález: I removed the construction of `\MaTeXbox` from the command `\cMaTeX`, since it is not needed to reconstruct `\MaTeXbox` with every use of `\cMaTeX`.

Answer (score 13):

This seems to work reasonably well in all sizes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}
\makeatletter
\def\matex@ssize{\larger[-2]\scshape}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MaTeX}{%
  \mbox{%
    M\kern-0.1em
    \raisebox{0.18ex}{\matex@ssize a}\kern-0.27em
    T\kern-0.27em
    \raisebox{0.18ex}{\matex@ssize e}\kern-0.1em
    X%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\MaTeX

\large\MaTeX

\Large\MaTeX

\LARGE\MaTeX

\huge\MaTeX

\Huge\MaTeX

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `ex` for horizontal measurements, but rather `em`. I've used `\kern` instead of `\hspace`, just for personal preference.

Comment: He had completely forgotten the package "relsize" I made some attempts to scalebox, but unsuccessful. «Don't use ex for horizontal measurements...» why?

Comment: @PabloGonzález `ex` is "vertically oriented" and won't necessarily be connected with the character widths. A rule of thumb is that 1em is the width of a capital "M", while 1ex is the height of a lowercase "x".

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareRobustCommand\MaTeX{%
  M\kern-.09em%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{0.075em}{\scalebox{0.5}{A}}\kern-.25em T%
  \kern-.25em%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{0.075em}{\scalebox{0.5}{E}}\kern-.08em X}}}
\begin{document}

\MaTeX

\huge\MaTeX

\tiny\MaTeX

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: which simply goes to show what i established, to my own satisfaction ages ago, that these ghastly bumpy-road logos don't work if you scale the font(s) they use.  the `\huge` example is obviously too loose (could do with smaller horizontal spacing), and the `\tiny` example is too crushed (could possibly work by reducing the size of the snuck-in letters).  i actually published a tugboat article about this effect (and the hideous technique i used to get around the problem).  it happens with _any_ bumpy-road logo you define.

Comment: Thanks Herbert, but its solution does not respect the spaces after writing \MaTEX (mounting the words on the logo)