# Is there any way to write words the same as TeX/LaTeX logo typography?

Tags: tikz-pgf, typography, logos

I am thinking about, typesetting my name and family name in my documents similar to the way TeX/LaTeX logos are typeset (not exactly, but having it a little changed), I mean having a function like `\logotype{enthusiastic student}` and have it appeared on my documents the way latex logo appears by coding `\LaTeX`.

I have not found such package or feature, if really a package is needed; and I do not know whether simpler solutions exist. I prepared a MWE using tikz package, however, using this package is not the thing I want since it is not so convenient for me to use between the normal text, etc.

[image]

```
% pdfLaTeX

\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node () at (0,0) {E};
\draw node () at (1.43,0) {THUSIASTIC};
\draw node () at (0.22,-0.11) {N};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw node () at (0,0) {E};
\draw node () at (0.53,0) {GI};
\draw node () at (1.275,0) {EER};
\draw node () at (0.22,-0.11) {N};
\draw node () at (0.82,-0.11) {N};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60499/7832

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL so related to what I am seeking for. Despite the technical part, It is very important one arrange the distances and how the letters are set to make a nice appearance of what is being typed. A little I tried, but I can see mine is not as beautiful as ***\LaTeX***!

Comment: In some occasions it is better to play with an acronym to be able to fit better the letters, an interesting variant is to reflect them as in logo of `XeTeX` :)

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL It is probably more of an art of logo and brand design than a TeX issue!

Comment: Indeed, I put the link related because I ever ventured to create my custom logo LaTeX style, good luck with yours :)

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL thank you very much, you are so kind. I am working on it to have my own LaTeX name logo as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just create and define your personal name/logo and put it in your pre-amble.

Here's \BibTex, for example:

```
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
```

I don't see why there would ever be a package specifically designed for the words or names you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I edited my question regarding the last paragraph of your answer.

Comment: “I don't see why there would ever be a package specifically designed for _XYZ_” – [u](https://ctan.org/pkg/sudokubundle)[m](https://ctan.org/pkg/chickenize)[.](https://ctan.org/pkg/skull)[.](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/avremu)[.](https://ctan.org/pkg/halloweenmath)

Answer (score 8):

For standard logos where there are characters raise or lowered, with kerns inserted between items, you can do as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definelogo}{mmmmO{}}
 {
  % #1 = command name
  % #2 = comma separated list of items
  % #3 = comma separated list of raising amounts
  % #4 = comma separated list of kerns
  % #5 = initial declaration
  \ee_definelogo:Nnnnn #1 {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ee_definelogo:Nnnnn
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__ee_definelogo_body_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { \clist_count:n { #2 } - 1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__ee_definelogo_body_tl
     {
      \dim_compare:nTF { \clist_item:nn { #3 } { ##1 } = 0pt }
       {
        \clist_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 }
       }
       {
        \exp_not:N \raisebox{ \clist_item:nn { #3 } { ##1 } } { \clist_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } }
       }
      \kern \clist_item:nn { #4 } { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__ee_definelogo_body_tl
   {
    \exp_not:N \raisebox{ \clist_item:nn { #3 } { -1 } } { \clist_item:nn { #2 } { -1 } }
   }
  \cs_new_protected:Npx #1
   {
    \exp_not:N \mbox
     {
      \exp_not:n { #5 }
      \exp_not:V \l__ee_definelogo_body_tl
      \exp_not:N \@
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definelogo{\BibTeX}{
  B,\textsc{i},\textsc{b},\TeX
}{
  0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt
}{
  -0.05em,-0.025em,-0.08em
}[\normalfont]

\definelogo{\ee}{
  E,N,THUSIASTIC,~,E,N,GINEER
}{
  0pt,-0.475ex,0pt,0pt,0pt,-0.475ex,0pt
}{
  -0.1em,-0.08em,0pt,0pt,-0.1em,-0.125em
}

\begin{document}

\BibTeX

\ee

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, how about something like `METAFONT`, `METAPOST`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fetamont}
\begin{document}
% Like a METAFONT
\textffm{ENTHUSIASTIC ENGINEER}\par
% Other
\textffm{Enthusiastic Engineer}\par
% A variant
\textffmw{ENTHUSIASTIC ENGINEER} \par
% MIx
\textffm{Enthusiastic} \textffmw{Engineer} \par
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Very nice, I have never used this package.

Comment: Just checking... the `\usepackage{...}` is *supposed* to be `fetamont` and not `metafont`? (I'm assuming some kind of inside joke?)

Comment: @COTO: _The logo font, known from logos like METAFONT or METAPOST, has been very limited in its collection of glyphs. The new typeface Fetamont extends the logo typeface..._

Comment: This package only allows access to the fonts that make up the logo...it is not related at all to the metapaost language.