# Showing definition of macros with custom characters?

Tags: macros, debugging

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\typeout{1.=\meaning\usebibmacro}
\typeout{2.=\meaning\usebibmacro{name:first-last}}

\makeatletter
\typeout{3.=\meaning\abx@macro@name:first-last}

\typeout{4.=\meaning \csname abx@macro@name:first-last \endcsname}
\typeout{5.=\expandafter\meaning \csname abx@macro@name:first-last \endcsname}
\typeout{6.=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\meaning \csname abx@macro@name:first-last \endcsname}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Running this with `pdflatex`, results with:

```
1.=\protected macro:#1->\ifcsundef {abx@macro@\detokenize {#1}} {\blx@error {Bi
bliography macro '\detokenize {#1}' undefined} {Use '\string \newbibmacro ' to 
define this macro}} {\csuse {abx@macro@\detokenize {#1}}}

2.=\protected macro:#1->\ifcsundef {abx@macro@\detokenize {#1}} {\blx@error {Bi
bliography macro '\detokenize {#1}' undefined} {Use '\string \newbibmacro ' to 
define this macro}} {\csuse {abx@macro@\detokenize {#1}}}{name:first-last}

3.=undefined:first-last

4.=\csnameabx@macro@name:first-last \endcsname 

5.=\relax

6.=\relax
```

... which is to say, the closest I can get to the definition of `\abx@macro@name:first-last` here is `\relax`; but I'm pretty sure that is not the case, because:

Even if `\abx@macro@name:first-last` is not defined verbatim under that name in `biblatex.sty`, look what `texdef` reports:

```
$ texdef -t latex -c book -p biblatex abx@macro@name:first-last  -f
\abx@macro@name:first-last first defined in "biblatex.sty".

\abx@macro@name:first-last:
macro:#1#2#3#4->\usebibmacro {name:delim}{#2#3#1}\usebibmacro {name:hook}{#2#3#1}\ifblank {#2}{}{\mkbibnamefirst {#2}\isdot \bibnamedelimd }\ifblank {#3}{}{\mkbibnameprefix {#3}\isdot \ifpunctmark {'} {} {\ifuseprefix {\bibnamedelimc }{\bibnamedelimd }}}\mkbibnamelast {#1}\isdot \ifblank {#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd \mkbibnameaffix {#4}\isdot }
```

... which is exactly what I was looking for!

One would think the `\protect` here (as in [macros - How can I see the "implementation" of the \LaTeX command? - TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17886/how-can-i-see-the-implementation-of-the-latex-command)) would be appropriate - yet I cannot see that `\abx@macro@name:first-last` is protected; the only thing I can see as problem is use of colon character in name (*which should then be handled by the `\csname`/`endcsname` approach, but isn't*).

Can anyone point out, how can I list this `\abx@macro@name:first-last` macro (and similar ones) from within Latex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking your steps in order:

1. Shows the meaning of `\usebibmacro`, which is a protected macro
2. Does exactly the same as (1), as `\meaning` does not expand the next token at all
3. Shows the meaning of the non-existent macro `\abx@macro@name`, as `:` is not a 'letter'
4. Shows the meaning of `\csname` (due to (2))
5. Shows the meaning of the non-existent macro `\abx@macro@name:first-last`, where there is a space at the end
6. Is the same as (5)

What you want here is

```
\expandafter\meaning\csname abx@macro@name:first-last\endcsname
```

with *no* space between `last` and `\endcsname`. This gives

```
macro:#1#2#3#4->\usebibmacro {name:delim}{#2#3#1}\usebibmacro {name:hook}{#2
#3#1}\ifblank {#2}{}{\mkbibnamefirst {#2}\isdot \bibnamedelimd }\ifblank {#3}{}
{\mkbibnameprefix {#3}\isdot \ifpunctmark {'} {} {\ifuseprefix {\bibnamedelimc 
}{\bibnamedelimd }}}\mkbibnamelast {#1}\isdot \ifblank {#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd \m
kbibnameaffix {#4}\isdot }
```

This has nothing to do with protection: you need simply to watch spaces.

(By the way, `biblatex` does definitions in `biblatex.def` and the standard styles, rather than in `biblatex.sty`.)

Comment: Ah, those damn spaces! `:/` whowoulddathunkit `:)` Many thanks for the answer, @JosephWright - cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Your test number 5 is the closest:

```
\typeout{5.=\expandafter\meaning \csname abx@macro@name:first-last\endcsname}
```

would be correct (you have a space before `\endcsname` that is significant).

The `\expandafter` is necessary so that `\meaning` finds the right token; in example 4 you get simply the meaning of `\csname`.

---

The following input, compiled from the terminal,

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xshowbibmacro{name:first-last}
```

will give

```
> \abx@macro@name:first-last=macro:
#1#2#3#4->\usebibmacro {name:delim}{#2#3#1}\usebibmacro {name:hook}{#2#3#1}\ifb
lank {#2}{}{\mkbibnamefirst {#2}\isdot \bibnamedelimd }\ifblank {#3}{}{\mkbibna
meprefix {#3}\isdot \ifpunctmark {'} {} {\ifuseprefix {\bibnamedelimc }{\bibnam
edelimd }}}\mkbibnamelast {#1}\isdot \ifblank {#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd \mkbibnamea
ffix {#4}\isdot }.
```

With the `xpatch` package you have also available

```
\xpatchbibmacro
\xpretobibmacro
\xapptobibmacro
```

which are the analog of `\patchcmd`, `\pretocmd` and `\apptocmd` provided by `etoolbox`.

The first argument to these commands is the string that one would use as argument to `\usebibmacro`. There's no `\xmeaning`: such debugging is best done from the terminal.

Comment: Many thanks for that @egreg - difficult to choose this time, but added accept to JosephWright's answer, as it provides a breakdown of my mistakes.. Although both of you point out the mistake with the spaces - and I truly appreciate the pointer to `xpatch` in this answer! (_btw, I also tried `show2e`s `\showcmd`, it also reports `\relax`_). Many thanks again - cheers!