# Where is the documentation?

Tags: documentation

Where or how do I find the documentation for a given Latex command?

For example, in R I get the documentation for `mean()` with `?mean` or at the manual pages http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/mean.html. In Java there are the Javadocs to tell me what parameters a method takes an what it returns.

What about LaTeX? If I want to know how to use the `\caption` command, for example, where is its documentation?

Every time I face a problem, I Google it up and get some blog, StackExchange or else that solves my problems but I never get to the formal documentation of a command so I never actually know why something works the way it does!

Comment: LaTeX is not a monolithic system: it's a series of parts written by different people. As such, the documentation is also in parts. For the LaTeX kernel, any good introduction will cover things (we have a [question on that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)). For add-on packages, `texdoc <package>` at the Command Line/Terminal should open the docs for that package.

Comment: It is also worth to have a look to [How can I see the “implementation” of the \LaTeX command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17886/13304)

Comment: I used R long before I started using LaTeX, so I sympathize very strongly with your question. I had the very same question myself. As other people point out, you need to look into the documentation for the package the command belongs to (a separate question is how you can find out what package that is!). But be prepared for much frustration, since many (most?) packages are quite poorly documented and quite cryptic.

Comment: See also [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/)

Answer (score 3):

Most distributions came with `texdoc` programm. Open a command line/terminal window and type

```
texdoc <package name>
```

where `<package name>` is the name of the class, style for which you want some documentation.

For example for `biblatex`, use `texdoc biblatex` and you read the PDF with Biblatex manual

Comment: Thank you. I guess texdoc or CTAN (thanks Romain Picot) is the closest to what I asked. However, texdoc open the docs for the whole package which you have to search and you have to remember which package a command comes from. I was hoping for something more direct like "textdoc <package> <command>". As I said, like in R invoking "help(mean)"

Comment: And exactly how should `texdoc` make your PDF reader jump to a certain page?

Comment: @daleif I think the OP was imaging a more structured documentation approach where each command has some form of database entry, rather than the free-form nature of the current LaTeX documentation.

Comment: @JosephWright, I know. BUt as others have mentioned, for LaTeX this would be an impossible dream.

Answer (score 3):

You have an easy and up-to-date access to the package documentations through the TeX Catalogue on Line, that you can find, e.g. [here:](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/alpha.html)

[image]

It's enough to have a bookmark in your favourite browser.

For a general help on LaTeX, you have the LaTeX Help e-book, which is in `.chm` format (compiled html), that you can find [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/LatexHelpBook). I don't know if it works on other platforms than Windows:

[image]

Comment: The catalog can be found now at [The TeX Catalogue OnLine, Alphabetic Ctan Edition](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/obsolete/help/Catalogue/alpha.html) but it's "obsolete" anyway so it should be equivalent to <https://www.ctan.org/pkg/catalogue>.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the package can be found on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/). They have an up-to-date documentation. Command which are part of the package have their documentation with them too.

Comment: What if I don't know what package a command is because I am mercilessly copy-pasting things and have no idea what I'm doing?