# What internal command(s) does \hspace call?

Tags: macros

I know that (by [\hspace vs. \hspace*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89082/hspace-vs-hspace)) the command `\hspace*` calls the internal commands

```
\vrule width 0pt \nobreak \hskip 1cm \hskip 0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt
```

but which command(s) does `\hspace` use? Is there a way to see the implementation of `\hspace`?

Comment: Could you say what you are aiming to achieve? Depending on the code you might find `\hspace` or the primitive `\hskip` code being used for arbitrary spacing.

Comment: Yes basically I want to learn how to program in LaTeX, then I want to know what the commands (at least the basic) do!

Comment: Ah, an (English) language thing: 'what commands calls `\hspace`' can be interpreted as meaning 'Which commands use `\hspace` internally?' while you mean 'How is `\hspace` implemented?' or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\show` or `\meaning` to see individual commands but I usually have `latex.ltx` in my emacs (editor) buffer, you can find your copy with kpsewhich (or just look in the log of any latex file for the file path to `article.cls` etc)

On my system

```
$ kpsewhich latex.ltx
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
```

At line 1308 you see

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\hspace{\@ifstar\@hspacer\@hspace}
\def\@hspace#1{\hskip #1\relax}
\def\@hspacer#1{\vrule \@width\z@\nobreak
                \hskip #1\hskip \z@skip}
```

searching in the file will show that `\hspace` does not appear except in those lines so no command defined in the format uses `\hspace` in its definition.

You can also see a typeset pdf version of the same by going

```
texdoc source2e
```

Comment: If they're defined by `\def`, why do they appear as `long`? Is it possible that `amsmath` redefines them?

Comment: @tohecz The only one that is long is the one defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`

Answer (score 5):

```
\makeatletter
\show\hspace
  % \hspace=macro: ->\protect \hspace  .
\expandafter\show\csname hspace \endcsname
  % \hspace =\long macro: ->\@ifstar \@hspacer \@hspace .
\show\@hspace
  % > \@hspace=macro: #1->\hskip #1\relax .
```

So it's `\hskip` that gets called. The `\expandafter\show\csname` trick [has been explained before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17888).

Comment: You could also do `\let\protect\show\hspace` to get to the `\@hspace` step.

Comment: @JosephWright that's what I usually do, but best to mention to do that in a local group, otherwise latex will behave a little strangely:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought about adding the grouping, but most of the time this is best done in a 'demo' file that you then stop processing so missed it out

Comment: `\usepackage{xpatch}` and `\xshowcmd\hspace`.