# How to \show the code of the command \autoref?

Tags: hyperref, tex-core, debugging

Edit: I think this is a duplicate of [How can I see the "implementation" of the \LaTeX command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17886/5699) .

I wanted to see the code for the hyperref `\autoref` command, so created this simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\show\autoref
\end{document}
```

However, in the log output, instead of the code, I see:

```
> \autoref=macro:
->\protect \autoref  .
l.4 \show\autoref
```

Changing line 4 to `\show\section` shows the code for `\section`, as expected:

```
> \section=\long macro:
->\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@ }{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont \Large \bfseries }.
l.4 \show\section
```

How can I get the actual code for `\autoref`?

Comment: voted to close as dup, my answer here is same as Joseph's over there (clearly latex-team group-think)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *is* the code for `\autoref` if you want to see the code for the internal command `\autoref_` (with a space) then

```
{\let\protect\show\autoref}
```

works

```
> \autoref =macro:
->\leavevmode \@ifstar {\HyRef@autoref \@gobbletwo }{\HyRef@autoref \hyper@@lin
k }.
\autoref ->\protect \autoref  

l.4 {\let\protect\show\autoref
                              }
```

Comment: Neat trick. Using `\expandafter\show\csname autoref \endcsname` works too.

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the tex faq: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ltxcmds

An expl3-variant to show the internal command (which ends with a space as David mentioned):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn\cs_show:c{autoref~}\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```