# Typesetting an integer interval

Tags: spacing

I am trying to typeset a integer interval like this: `[0..m-1]`

However, the space between `0`,`.`, and `m - 1` are too small. Is there a package to improve this?

Comment: $[0 \dots m-1]$?

Comment: @Rmano It must be two dots.

Comment: \\(\llbracket a, b \rrbracket\\)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's see how I can make a command that is like a `\dots` but with two dots. Firstly, I use the wisdom of TeX.SE and find how to [find the content of a standard definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17888/38080); then a bit of command line:

```
[romano:~] % texdef -t latex dots  
\dots:
macro:->\protect \dots  
\dots :
\long macro:->\ifmmode \mathellipsis \else \textellipsis \fi 

[romano:~] % texdef -t latex mathellipsis
\mathellipsis:
macro:->\mathinner {\ldotp \ldotp \ldotp }
```

and finally:

```
 \newcommand{\twodots}{\mathinner {\ldotp \ldotp}}
```

which results in:

[image: twodots macro]

(This is just for math mode, but you can easily extend it for text too, mimicking the `\dots` definition)

Answer (score 13):

I like the two dots, too. My usual code is

```
[a\mathrel{{.}\,{.}}\nobreak b]
```

of course hidden in a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\isep}{\mathrel{{.}\,{.}}\nobreak}

\begin{document}

$[0\isep m-1]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more elaborate solution for coping with intervals of any kind, while keeping a syntax that doesn't force a choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\interval}{O{}>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { calcolo/interval } { o, #1 }
  \bool_if:NTF { \l_calcolo_interval_auto_bool }
   {\mleft\l_calcolo_interval_left_tl}
   {\mathopen{\l_calcolo_interval_size_tl\l_calcolo_interval_left_tl}}
  \calcolo_interval_set:nn #2
  \bool_if:NTF { \l_calcolo_interval_auto_bool }
   {\mright\l_calcolo_interval_right_tl}
   {\mathclose{\l_calcolo_interval_size_tl\l_calcolo_interval_right_tl}}
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \calcolo_interval_set:nn
 {
  #1 \mathrel{{.}\,{.}}\nobreak #2
 }
\keys_define:nn { calcolo/interval }
 {
  size .code:n =
   \tl_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { * }
    { \bool_set_true:N \l_calcolo_interval_auto_bool }
    { \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_size_tl { #1 } },
  o .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_left_tl { ( }
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_right_tl { ) },
  oo .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_left_tl { ( }
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_right_tl { ) },
  c .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_left_tl { [ }
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_right_tl { ] },
  cc .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_left_tl { [ }
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_right_tl { ] },
  oc .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_left_tl { ( }
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_right_tl { ] },
  co .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_left_tl { [ }
   \tl_set:Nn \l_calcolo_interval_right_tl { ) },
  o .value_forbidden:n = true,
  oo .value_forbidden:n = true,
  c .value_forbidden:n = true,
  cc .value_forbidden:n = true,
  oc .value_forbidden:n = true,
  co .value_forbidden:n = true,
 }

\tl_new:N \l_calcolo_interval_left_tl
\tl_new:N \l_calcolo_interval_right_tl
\tl_new:N \l_calcolo_interval_size_tl
\bool_new:N \l_calcolo_interval_auto_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

$\interval{a,b}$

$\interval[c]{a,b}$

$\interval[co]{a,b}$

$\interval[oc]{a,b}$

$\interval[size=\Big]{a,b}$

\bigskip

$\interval[size=*,co]{\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{\dfrac{3}{4}},b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution with `mathtools` and `xparse`. I define a  command `\Iintvl{m,n}`. You need a font which contains the relevant delimiters, `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` (`fourier` and `stmaryrd`) or equivalents (`MnSymbol` and `MdSymbol` have `\lsem` and `\rsem`). The star version of the command adapts the size of the delimiters to the contents, and you can fine-tune their size with an optional argument (`\big, \Big, …`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, stmaryrd}
\usepackage{xparse} \DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\Iintv}[1]{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}{\iintvargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\iintvargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}
{\iintvargsaux#1} %
\NewDocumentCommand{\iintvargsaux}{mm} {#1\mkern1.5mu..\mkern1.5mu#2}

\begin{document}

\[ \Iintv{-2,5} \quad \Iintv*{2^n, 2^{n + 1} } \quad \Iintv*{2^{2^n} + 1, 2^{2^{n + 1}} + 1}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `\enleadertwodots` in the `stix` package is perfect (aside from tiny spacing). I've added a couple variations on spacing so you can see how it looks:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}

\[[1\, \enleadertwodots\, m-1] \quad [1 \enleadertwodots\, m-1] \quad [1 \enleadertwodots m-1]\]

\end{document}
```

[image: p1]

I found this after scanning through [this huge list of symbols in latex](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Much less robust than others (it can of course be made more robust, but may be this is enough), but it might be nice looking and readable code

```
\def\intv#1[#2..#3]{\mathopen{#1[}#2\mathrel{{.}\,{.}}\nobreak#3\mathclose{#1]}}
$
\intv[a..b]
\intv\big[a..b]
\intv\Bigg[\frac{a}{b}..c]
$
```

If you need `\left[ .. \right]` I can add the code.

Comment: `\nobreak` is necessary after `\mathrel{...}` or TeX would be allowed to put a line break.

Comment: Sorry, I definitely tried to copy your output code (while varying the input) but miss that one.