# vertical spacing in multiline gather with amsmath

Tags: spacing, amsmath

I have `gather*` section with three lines. the lines appear all bunched up with hardly any space between them. How can I spread them out a little?

I tried `\belowdisplayskip=12pt` but no matter what value I chose there was no discernible difference to anything

```
\f{gather*}
    R_{address} = \frac{4700}{\left(\frac{17}{\mathrm{Address} - 15.5} - 1\right)} \\*

    \mathrm{Address} = \frac{17}{\left(\frac{4700}{R_{address}} + 1\right)} + 15.5

    \mathrm{Address} \in [16\mathrel{{.}\,{.}}\nobreak 31] \\*
\f}
```

Where `\f{environment}` is equivalent to `begin{environment}` for Doxygen that I am using.

Comment: `\baselineskip` is the controlling length or use `\\[1cm]` instead of `\\ ` also `\mathrm{address}`

Comment: also why `\nobreak`? (there is no possibility of a break at that point)

Comment: `\nobreak` because people don't like if you don't: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304685/120371

Comment: that's inline math so rather different.

Comment: `\mathrm{address}` on the `R_` you mean? I get an error if I do that...

Comment: yes never set words in math italic, the whole point of the math font is to separate letters and make it look like a product of variables not a word. `R_{\mathrm{address}}` will not give an error

Comment: Ah I think when I tried it I may have used `R_\mathrm{address}` or something. I'll give it another shot

Comment: Hmm `\baselineskip` did nothing but that may be down to Doxygen . `\\[1cm]` worked. Is it possible to combine that with the `*` to prevent page breaks?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Also if you'd like to make your comment an answer for the `\\[1cm]`. As that worked for me.

Comment: this is align rather than gather but all the ams displays are the same so:

Comment: an explicit skip *plus* the asterisk to suppress a page break will work if input in this order: `\\*[1cm]`.  if the asterisk follows the optional skip, it will simply be set at the beginning of the next line.  (just tested.  doesn't seem to be mentioned in the user's guide; will make a note to check that and add if it's really not there.)