# Are there any command for producing the BibTeX logo?

Tags: bibtex, logos

we all know `\TeX` produces the TeX logo and `\LaTeX` produces the LaTeX logo. But there seems no command like `\BibTeX` for producing the BibTeX logo, while Wikipedia adopts a complicated workaround: [`\mathrm{B{\scriptstyle{IB}} \! T\!_{\displaystyle E} \! X}`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX). So is there no simple command? (I think `Bib\TeX` is no good because the case does not conform to the official one)

Comment: Possible duplicate? See Herbert's answer to [How to write (La)TeX (with braces)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11095/3954)

Comment: Yes, you are right. That helps :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It used to be the case that the [dtk-logos](http://mirrors.ctan.org/usergrps/dante/dtk/dtk-logos.sty) package provided commands such as `\BibTeX'. It is part of the [dtk](https://ctan.org/pkg/dtk) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dtk-logos}
\begin{document}
\BibTeX  % Doesn't work in TeXLive 2015
\end{document}
```

However, `dtk-logos` is still under development, and subject to change. A safer option is to use the [hologo package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hologo).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hologo}
\begin{document}
\hologo{BibTeX}
\end{document}
```

In fact, the current version of `dtk-logos` loads `hologo`, but I think it's probably best to load `hologo` directly, until development of `dtk-logos` is complete.

Comment: More complicated than I thought: {B\kern-.05em%\hbox{$\m@th$\csname S@\f@size\endcsname\fontsize\sf@size\z@\math@fontsfalse\selectfont I\kern-.025emB}\kern-.08em\-\TeX}

Comment: @Ian Thompson: the current versions of dtklogos no longer support this, you may want to update your answer.  See mine below.

Comment: @akim --- Thanks for pointing this out. I knew about the change, but had long since forgotten about this question. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 12):

FWIW, [Oren Patashnik's original BibTeX documentation](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) defines a `\BibTeX` command in the preamble of the corresponding [.tex file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.tex):

```
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
```

The larger title version is hand-crafted like this:

```
\title{B\kern-.05em{\large I}\kern-.025em{\large B}\kern-.08em\TeX ing}
```

Comment: Incidentally, `\rm` and `\sc` are deprecated. [Use `\textrm` and `\textsc` instead.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151899/22201)

Comment: so for those who want to copy version of the original for latex2e: ```\def\BibTeX{\textrm{B\kern-.05em\textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}```

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there's an *official* BibTeX logo. Usually I adopt `\textsc{Bib}\TeX`, but also `\textsc{Bib}\negthinspace\TeX` might be used. The `$\mathrm{B\scriptstyle IB}\!$\TeX` trick might be used if the font doesn't have small caps.

Answer (score 3):

The version of `dtklogos` that I have (2014/11/15 v2.2) no longer defines `\BibTeX`, rather it loads the `hologo` package.  The latter does not define `\BibTeX`, but `\hologo{BibTeX}`.  Unfortunately, `dtklogos` did not install a backward compatible command for it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{hologo}
\begin{document}
\hologo{BibTeX}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is better suited as an edit of the accepted answer.

Comment: Really?  At first I made this a comment of the accepted answer, but it seemed too hidden so I made it another answer.  But editing the accepted answer felt uneasy/unethical...  Is this really the preferred way?

Comment: You can ask Ian to include it in his answer, according to his profile, he was online three hours ago. If you are sure he has seen it but ignored it, a new nswer is ok. Though editing would be ok as well. Many will have your answer at the very bottom  and never scroll down to read it.