# Always \textrm, never \rm? A counterexample?

Tags: best-practices, obsolete

Let us see the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{theorem}
TFAE
\begin{itemize}
\item[(i)]
$0<1$;
\item[(ii)]
$1>0$.
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

But I want (i)'s Roman:

\begin{theorem}
TFAE
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textrm{(i)}]
$0<1$;
\item[\textrm{(ii)}]
$1>0$.
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

Alas, still italic, but\ldots

\begin{theorem}
TFAE
\begin{itemize}
\item[\rm(i)]
$0<1$;
\item[\rm(ii)]
$1>0$.
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And `\textrm`, which should be better than an obsolete `\rm` (I know the differences of using them) doesn't work as one can expect. Is it an argument for using `\rm` from time to time?

Comment: With `enumitem`, you could use `\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\roman*)]`.

Comment: BTW: both the `memoir` class and the KOMA-Script classes issue warnings if any of those deprecated commands is used. KOMA-Script announced that it will even remove the definitions for those commands in one of the next releases...

Comment: oh no, please do learn to use `enumerate` instead of misusing `itemize` like this. There are others reading this site, and we'd rather not have them getting the idea that this is a good methodology.

Comment: @egreg, I'd even go as far as redefining the setting controling `[(i)]` (the `shortlabels` option) to include the `\upshape` or `\textnormal{...}`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No, `\rm` is deprecated and should not be used in a LaTeX2e document (ConTeXt and plain are of course different). What is happening here is deliberate. Issuing `\textrm` means that the current font family should be roman, not  sanserif or monospaced. However, it does *not* alter the current shape (upright/italic/slanted) or weight (light/medium/heavy): that's the entire point of the LaTeX2e 'New Font Selection Scheme'. In contrast, `\rm` sets a fixed font: upright, roman, medium weight.

What you therefore are looking for here is altering the font shape, not the family: `\textup` is the command you are after (*cf.* `\textit`, `\textsl`). Of course, in a real case you should be applying this as an change to the general theorem style not just on an *ad hoc* basis.

Comment: Not part of the answer, but do you _really_ want upright here? Every published work I've ever looked at in detail uses italic for list numbering.

Comment: If the client wants to... And he has a good sense of beauty of mathematical text, in general...

Comment: I tend to agree with @PrzemysławScherwentke, sometimes it just looks wrong with those items in italic. As long as one is consistent...

Comment: @JosephWright -- some publishers prefer upright item labels.  (the ams is one such.)  but a better way to do it is to use `\upshape`.  just take a look at `amsart` and friends.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I did say 'that I've looked at in detail': as you might imagine, that's primarily chemistry publishers.

Comment: @JosephWright -- and you did say that in a comment, not in the answer.  (i upvoted the answer because it's a good answer.)  but, as your two comments together make clear, the style may vary by discipline, and it's a good idea for an author to be aware of the conventions of the discipline for which s/he is writing.

Answer (score 8):

No, if you want to be sure the item labels are in "`\rm` style", you should use

```
{\normalfont(i)}
```

Of course, as @egreg pointed out, you might want to use `enumitem` and redefine the item labels globally, since local changes like this one are non-systematic and non-error-prone. Therefore the following in your preamble might help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\normalfont(\roman*)}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
TFAE
\begin{enumerate}
\item
$0<1$;
\item
$1>0$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One important factor derived from Joseph Wright's answer, which should be emphasized: 
`\textrm`, `\textbf`, `\textit`, etc. are not simple equivalents of plain `\rm`, `\bf`, `\it`, etc. in local mode. Moreover: their meanings are of different types in LaTeX (e.g. family vs. shape).

Comment: Well, you mix `\textrm` and `\rmfamily`. The `\text..` commands take argument as in `\textrm{Ahoj}`, whereas `\rmfamily` is the proper "new" version of `\rm`, as in `{\rmfamily Ahoj}`. I put "new" in quotation marks since NFSS is already quite old.

Comment: @tohecz Indeed: I forgot adding the information of local behaviour.