# Difference between \xx{} and \mathxx{}?

Tags: math-mode

What is the difference between math font `\xx{}` and `\mathxx{}` where `xx=rm, bf, cal`?

When I use them it seems that the `\xx{}` formats all the words after it.

But `\mathxx{}` formats only what is between brackets `{}`.

Is this correct?

Comment: What you noted is the cause why `\bf`, `\rm` etc. should not be used any longer, but rather `\textbf{}`, `\textrm{}` etc. and this will also distinguish them clearly from `\mathbf{}` etc. as well as `text` to `\math` mode, so the answer is **yes, it is correct**

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/will-two-letter-font-style-commands-bf-it-ever-be-resurrected-in-latex

Comment: Oh, I forgot: Welcome to TeX.SX

Comment: Newer versions of the `KOMA` classes explicitly shipout warnings if the code encounters `\bf` etc. command, this as tiny remark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commands like `\bf` are obsolete in LaTeX. See, e.g., [Always \textrm, never \rm? A counterexample?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151897/always-textrm-never-rm-a-counterexample).
Moreover, the proper usage is `{\bf your text}`, because it is a global switch. In math mode you can use `\mathxx` or also `\textxx`. In particular, in the former spaces are omitted, in the latter they behave like in normal text.