# Why does align come out of math mode?

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

The following:

```
\begin{align*}
        F
        =
        {}&a^2+b^2=c^2 
         \notag\\\rm{subject~to} & \; 
         5+1=6 \;\rm{ and }\;  a+b=c.
\end{align*}
```

produces a+b=c that isn't in math mode. Why?

Comment: Because `\rm` is a switch and not a command taking an argument.  Use `\text{...}` instead.

Comment: Because you've used `\rm` which (1) shouldn't be used in LaTeX since it was made obsolete a few decades ago and (2) does not take an argument, since it is a switch. It switches to the default serif family until the end of the current group or the end of the document. You haven't provided a complete example, but this has zilch to do with `align` and everything to do with abuse of font macros.

Comment: Write `\text{subject to` and `\text{ and }`. Don't use `\rm`.

Comment: another potential duplicatea; [Difference between \xx{} and \mathxx{}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191287/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the incorrect -- it should be `{\rm ...}`, not `\rm{...}` -- and inappropriate -- `\rm` is badly deprecated; use `\text{...}` -- usage of `\rm` would appear to be just severe of several problems contained in the code.

- No purposeful aligning appears to be going on across the two rows. Hence, use a `gather*` environment, *not* an `align*` environment.
- Don't use `\notag`: there's simply no point doing so in either a `gather*` or an `align*` environment.
- Place the entire second row in the argument of a `\text` directive, and use inline math mode for the two formulas contained in the second row.

(Note that I'm note passing judgment on the actual mathematics -- that's not really the subject of this posting, is it?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*} % not "align*"
    F = a^2+b^2=c^2 \\
    \text{subject to $5+1=6$ and $a+b=c$.}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - this fixed it! (The math was obviously fake garbage, and the align*, \notag, and lack of & were hold-overs from gutting out the actual equations that I'm using.)

Answer (score -1):

\rm in curly bracket

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \begin{document}
       \begin{align*}
       F
       =
      {}&a^2+b^2=c^2 
       \\{\rm subject~to} & \; 
        5+1=6 \;{\rm and }\;  a+b=c.
      \end{align*}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: `\rm` has been deprecated for more than 20 years.

Comment: That's a bad answer. -1