# I get a error undefined old font command '\rm'

Tags: fonts, koma-script

when I use the following document class i got the error "old font command '\rm' ". any suggestion how to solve this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,chapterprefix=true,
               twoside,openright,listof=totoc, 
               BCOR7.5mm]{scrreprt}
```

Comment: Don't use \rm but \rmfamily. Or type `h` at the error then you will get a message in the terminal and the log what you can also do.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151897/always-textrm-never-rm-a-counterexample

Comment: This command has been obsolete for more  than 20 years! You should use `\rmfamily` for a switch ot `\textrm{...}` for a delimited scope.

Comment: OFF-Topic: with `scrreprt` the right option is `bcor=7.5mm` ...

Comment: If you don't care about using commands that are deprecated for over 20 years or using packages with those old commands, this is the way to go: `enabledeprecatedfontcommands`

Comment: All questions that could be a duplicate have quite pointless answers that address the reason and provide fixes, but none explains the error message and how to reactivate old commands. Well, some do, but not in the expected way.

Comment: @Johannes_B Old commands should never be used in a document. In case the problem stems from a poorly written package, workarounds can be devised, but in my opinion reactivating the deprecated commands is out of the question or the very last resource.

Comment: @egreg But we have the memoir equivalent somewhere in an answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B correct, but egregs comment also applies to memoir. Users should be forced to give up those old and bad habits. I regularly see users make `\newtheorem{example} [theorem] {Example} ` in articles and start every example environment by `\rm` to make it upright. They generally should be forced to learn how to thi gs correctly

Comment: Related: [what to replace `\it` with in Math mode to make scrbook happy?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313622/what-to-replace-it-with-in-math-mode-to-make-scrbook-happy)

Comment: @daleif i don't think we can force people to learn anything  by omitting information.  We can certainly not help many by adding answers to individuals without eliminating bad souces #wikibooks but this completely off-topic here.

Comment: @Johannes_B sure, but it us important to note to users that using that enable feature us not a good idea, otherwise those enable answers will be the predominant answers in searches for those problems.

Comment: @egreg if you are unhappy about people using this command, you should talk to mathscinet. I personally have not typed "\rm" in a latex file once, yet virtually all my articles implicitly contain it because mathscinet references use it. Also I don't see the point of being condescending about people using "old commands": commands that stop being commands are a problem of language design, not a user error.

Comment: @StefanWitzel MathSciNet is a very particular case, because they used (or still use) AMS-TeX.

Comment: @egreg maybe particular, but definitely ubiquitous. I suppose you'd say "get your bibtex data from a source that uses LaTeX"?