# How do I define a custom infix operator in math mode? An alternative to \operatorname

Tags: math-mode

As an example of what I do *not* want, take

```
$\mathrm{C} \operatorname{F} 4$
```

produces different spacing between the star and the operands than

```
$a \ast 4$
```

How do I mitigate this?

I can't use definitions outside of the math mode environment.

In this specific case, I want to use `\ast \ast` as an infix symbol.

Comment: Could you precise the question? What are you trying to do, exactly? Also, you [should not use ``\rm``](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151897/always-textrm-never-rm-a-counterexample), use ``\mathrm`` instead.

Comment: fixed it. thanks for pointing that out. but \rm suffices for my current goal, if I do anything serious ill use \mathrm

Comment: your question is very unclear, but `\mathbin{...}` will give `...` the spacing rules that + has.

Comment: Do you want “C*” to behave like a single operator?

Comment: @egreg no. I was just using \ast as an example, using which Inoticsed the discrepancy. I want to use something else

Comment: Maybe, if you describe what you *want* to get rather than what you *don't*…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\astast}{\mathbin{{\ast}{\ast}}}
\begin{document}
$A \astast B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: `\ast` is a binary operator, with the spacing that comes with it. Enclosing it in braces `{\ast}` turns it into an *ordinary* math atom, so two of these next to each other have no intervening space. Then `\mathbin` turns the whole construct into a binary operator.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to emulate the “double asterisk” `**` used for exponentiation, then

```
\mathbin{{*}{*}}
```

is what you need.

The asterisk `*` by itself produces a **Bin** atom, without needing `\mathbin` around it. However two **Bin** atoms in a row don't make a single **Bin** atom, because a **Bin** requires operands around it. Thus the second `*` would be made into an ordinary symbol.

However, you can make any subformula into a **Bin** atom by typing it as the argument to `\mathbin`. By rule, no spacing would be used between the two asterisks with `\mathbin{**}` (the first would be turned into a unary symbol, just like in `-1`, and the second into an ordinary, because of the rule above). However, it's better to be more careful and type

```
\mathbin{{*}{*}}
```

(the braces hide the nature of `*` turning it into an ordinary), because the output of

```
\mathbin{***}
```

might surprise you. To the contrary, `\mathbin{{*}{*}{*}}` would not have the problem.