# Getting the BibTeX logo, analogously to \LaTeX

Tags: bibtex

I can't find the analogue of the `\LaTeX` command that produces the BibTeX logo:

[image: BibTeX logo]

Comment: Also see [How to write (La)TeX (with parentheses) (or any other TeX-related logo)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11095/5764) for a more comprehensive list of TeX-related logos.

Answer (score 4):

After much gnashing of teeth, trying `\BiBTeX`, `\BIBTeX`, `\BibTeX`, `\bibTeX`, ... in the hope that such a command would be defined *somewhere* and looking through SO, I looked through [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX), found [Oren Patashnik's original BibTeX documentation](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf), located the corresponding [.tex file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.tex) and found that a \BibTeX command was defined in its preamble:

```
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
```

FWIW, the larger title version is hand-crafted like this:

```
\title{B\kern-.05em{\large I}\kern-.025em{\large B}\kern-.08em\TeX ing}
```

EDIT: [Duh. My bad.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18089/are-there-any-command-for-the-styled-bibtex/) Well, since someone already upvoted the answer, the Q may still be useful here, so I won't self-delete... unless someone prefers I do? Please comment if so.

Comment: Incidentally, `\rm` and `\sc` are deprecated. [Use `\textrm` and `\textsc` instead.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151899/22201)