# Strange problem : BibTex raises undefined sequence for \BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

New to Latex, I just encounter a very strange problem that I cannot use `\BibTeX` in reference file, when I add `\BibTeX` to my bib file in the tile filed and reference it in the document, it raises the error of undefined control sequence, but I saw in other pdf, it was used and correctly generated. Can anyone help? 
Thanks very much!
The bib entry is like this:

```
@electronic{IEEEexample:bibtexguide,
  author        = "Ki-Joo Kim",
  title         = "A {{\BibTeX}} Guide via Examples",
  howpublished  = "{bibtex\_guide.pdf}",
  url           = "http://www.geocities.com/kijoo2000/",
  month         = apr,
  year          = "2004"
}
```

the error from the bbl file is like :

```
\bibitem{IEEEexample:bibtexguide}
\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing
K.-J. Kim. (2004, Apr.) A {{\BibTeX}} guide via examples. {bibtex\_guide.pdf}.
  [Online]. Available: \url{http://www.geocities.com/kijoo2000/}
\BIBentrySTDinterwordspacing
```

Comment: Welcome! That's not an error. That's a bibliography entry. The `.bbl` is your bibliography. The log will contain the error. But `\BibTex` is never usually defined, unlike `\BibTeX`. So if your error is the one you report, you probably just misspelt the macro. (Or mis-punctuated it or whatever you call it when you fail to copy weirdly-capitalised thingies accurately.)

Comment: But `\BibTeX` is also not a core command. Did you load a package or class which defines it? Or did you define it?

Comment: Write `Bib\TeX` instead of `\BibTeX`.

Comment: `\newcommand{\BibTeX}{B\kern-0.08em\textsc{i\kern-0.017emb}\kern-0.15em\TeX}` should work...

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18089/15925