# Write a word with the \LaTeX style

Tags: typography

I would like to know how can I write a text in the same way that `\LaTeX` is written, I mean the even characters must be a little below the rest or the opposite with the odd characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define macros for that. Here are the definitions of `\LaTeX` and `\LaTeXe`, from `ltlogos.dtx`, also to be found in `latex.ltx`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern-.36em%
        {\sbox\z@ T%
         \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
                              \fontsize\sf@size\z@
                              \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
                              A}%
                        \vss}%
        }%
        \kern-.15em%
        \TeX}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeXe}{\mbox{\m@th
  \if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\boldmath\fi
  \LaTeX\kern.15em2$_{\textstyle\varepsilon}$}}
```

You could do it similar.

Perhaps also have a look at the [list of logos](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-braces-or-any-other-tex-related-logo/11097#11097) posted by Herbert.

If this looks too complicated: you could build LaTeX macros also using LaTeX commands, such as `\raisebox`.

Comment: Also the `dtklogos` package source code might be of interest.

Answer (score 16):

[This](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-1/tb91murzynowski-logo.pdf) document from TUGboat discusses some modifications to the LaTeX logo that adapts to various font changes. It includes both the original definition of `\LaTeX` as a well as a modified version:

Original `\LaTeX`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{%
  L\kern-.36em%
  {\sbox\z@ T%
    \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{%
      \check@mathfonts
      \fontsize\sf@size\z@
      \math@fontsfalse\selectfont A}%
    \vss}%
  }%
  \kern-.15em%
  \TeX}
```

Modified `\LaTeX`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{%
  {%
    L%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{\check@mathfonts
      \fontsize\sf@size\z@
      \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
      A}%
    \kern-.57\wd\z@
    \sbox\tw@ T%
    \vbox to\ht\tw@{\copy\z@ \vss}%
    \kern-.2\wd\z@}%
  {%
    \ifdim\fontdimen1\font=\z@
    \else
    \count\z@=\fontdimen5\font
    \multiply\count\z@ by 64\relax
    \divide\count\z@ by\p@
    \count\tw@=\fontdimen1\font
    \multiply\count\tw@ by\count\z@
    \divide\count\tw@ by 64\relax
    \divide\count\tw@ by\tw@
    \kern-\the\count\tw@ sp\relax
    \fi}%
  \TeX}
```

that, when compared, looks like this across some different fonts:

[image: Modified version of \LaTeX]

Suggested in Knuth's TeXbook, the original definition of `\TeX`:

```
\def\TeX{{\rm T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
```

From this you'll probably be able to modify your own text.