# special latex words

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write (La)TeX  (with braces) [or any other TeX-related logo]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-braces-or-any-other-tex-related-logo)

I'm looking for other specially formatted words in LaTeX similar to `\LaTeX` or `\TeX`. Does anyone know of a list (if there are any other words) and/or if there is one for TikZ?

Comment: TikZ is simply `Ti\emph{k}Z`, otherwise related: [How to write (La)TeX (with braces) or any other TeX-related logo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11095/16595) and (for a source example) [Write a word with the \LaTeX style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24242/16595)

Comment: Thanks, Qrrbbrbirlbel! I'm thinking those are all of them. Would you care to post as an answer that I can accept?