# How to render \Lyx like \LaTeX

Tags: macros, lyx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write (La)TeX  (with braces) [or any other TeX-related logo]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-braces-or-any-other-tex-related-logo)

Is there a macro defined somewhere that I can use so that `\LyX{}` renders like `\LaTeX` in pure LaTeX? This is really hard to google and grep for...

Comment: Sorry, don't understand exactly what you are looking for?  Please add some details.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-braces-or-any-other-tex-related-logo

Answer (score 5):

The logo `\TeX` is defined as follows in [`ltlogo.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/ltlogos.dtx):

```
\def\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX\@}
```

Subsequently, `\LaTeX` prepends the two characters `La` in a special way:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern-.36em%
  {\sbox\z@ T%
    \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
    \fontsize\sf@size\z@
    \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
    A}%
  \vss}%
}%
\kern-.15em%
\TeX}
```

Other TeX-related logos are also defined in this canonical way. As such, using similar techniques to manipulate the characters, you could do the following:

```
\def\LyX{L\kern-.2em% Define \LyX
  {\sbox\z@ X%
    \vbox to .9\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
        \fontsize\sf@size\z@
        \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
        Y}%
      \vss}%
  }%
\kern-.125emX\@}
```

Here is a minimal working example that showcases the three logos `\TeX`, `\LaTeX` and `\LyX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\LyX{L\kern-.2em% Define \LyX
  {\sbox\z@ X%
    \vbox to .9\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
        \fontsize\sf@size\z@
        \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
        Y}%
      \vss}%
  }%
\kern-.125emX\@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent \verb!\TeX!: \TeX \\
\noindent \verb!\LaTeX!: \LaTeX \\
\noindent \verb!\LyX!: \LyX
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX-LaTeX-LyX]