# How to print "LaTeX" as shown in many tutorials and books?

Tags: errors, latex-misc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write (La)TeX  (with braces) [or any other TeX-related logo]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-braces-or-any-other-tex-related-logo)

I came across the [tug tutorial](http://www.tug.org/twg/mactex/tutorials/ltxprimer-1.0.pdf), and writing down the very first basic example of printing simple document.

My LaTeX file is:

```
mt4k@laptop:$ cat myfile.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is my \emph{first} document prepared in \Latex.
\end{document}
```

I am getting the following message for `\Latex`:

```
mtk4@laptop:$ latex myfile.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./myfile.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang,     noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./myfile.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 ...my \emph{first} document prepared in \Latex
                                                  .
?
```

In the output pdf, the `Latex` word has been omitted. Can anyone tell me how to print words in that fashion? (In a way similar as the word 'LATEX' is printed in the pdf in the link above)

Please let me know if you need more info. Also I have searched the SO and this site, and couldn't find any similar question, If I have missed out, please point me to it.

Comment: It's `\LaTeX` not `\Latex`. Macro names are case-sensitive.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I closed this question as duplicate to another question which lists this and other logo macros.

Comment: ok. np, Got all the answers from original question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `\LaTeX` and not `\Latex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is my \emph{first} document prepared in \LaTeX.
\end{document}
```