# XeLaTeX logo with pdfLaTeX?

Tags: macros, xetex, pdftex, packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write (La)TeX  (with braces) [or any other TeX-related logo]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-braces-or-any-other-tex-related-logo)

I try to typeset the XeLaTeX logo in a document that has to be run through pdfLaTeX (for a journal). I know that the logo is in `xltxtra`, but loading this package breaks the pdfLaTeX run. Is there a way to use part of the `xltxtra` package? I looked at the code, but it does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `hologo` or `metalogo` packages, both implement it (among others) for pdftex and other engines.