# How is the LaTeX 2e made?

Tags: macros, characters, kerning, logos

I wanted to know how is the `\LaTeXe` symbol ([image: LaTeXe]) made, I mean, the command **definition** of superscripts and subscripts on the "L", "A"... letters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write (La)TeX (with braces) \[or any other TeX-related logo\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/5764).

Comment: @Werner: I disagree, the question you're linking to is about the macro names, not about how the macros typeset the letters.

Comment: @Stephen I'm not sure if we should declare a question a duplicate of another question if they need different accepted answers like this? At any rate, the two questions seem different enough to me to keep them separate.

Comment: @doncherry: Agreed, and this question here got good answers, too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The definitions from [`source2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e) (the listing of the LaTeX kernel):

```
% the TeX logo
\def\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX\@}

% the LaTeX logo
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern-.36em%
{\sbox\z@ T%
\vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
\fontsize\sf@size\z@
\math@fontsfalse\selectfont
A}%
\vss}%
}%
\kern-.15em%
\TeX}

% the LaTeX2e logo
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeXe}{\mbox{\m@th
\if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\boldmath\fi
\LaTeX\kern.15em2$_{\textstyle\varepsilon}$}}
```

Another way would be to run the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\show\csname LaTeXe \endcsname

\end{document}
```

The output console will show you the definition:

```
> \LaTeXe =\long macro:
->\mbox {\m@th \if b\expandafter \@car \f@series \@nil \boldmath \fi \LaTeX \ke
rn .15em2$_{\textstyle \varepsilon }$}.
```

Running now this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\show\csname LaTeX \endcsname

\end{document}
```

you'll get the definition of `\LaTeX`:

```
> \LaTeX =\long macro:
->L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \
sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX .
```

Finally, running

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\show\TeX

\end{document}
```

you get the `\TeX` definition:

```
> \TeX=macro:
->T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\@.
```

Comment: The same as Paul, but more complete answer. Thanks too.

Answer (score 5):

To find these definitions, you can use the `texdef` command (`\LaTeXe` calls `\LaTeX` and `\LaTeX` calls `\TeX`):

```
texdef -t latex LaTeXe LaTeX TeX
```

With the following result:

```
\LaTeXe:
macro:->\protect \LaTeXe  

\LaTeXe :
\long macro:->\mbox {\m@th \if b\expandafter \@car \f@series \@nil \boldmath \fi \LaTeX \kern .15em2$_{\textstyle \varepsilon }$}

\LaTeX:
macro:->\protect \LaTeX  

\LaTeX :
\long macro:->L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX 

\TeX:
macro:->T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\@
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know so much about plain TeX commands and I find it really useful, especially to learn. Thanks.