# How do I type TeX without using the command?

Tags: formatting, height

How am I able to format TeX without using the command? I know I can use \TeX and it'll do it automatically but I'd like to do it manually for other stuff.

Comment: Related/duplicate(s): [How to write (La)TeX (with parentheses) (or any other TeX-related logo)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11095/5764); [How is the LaTeX 2e made?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80332/5764)

Answer (score 5):

If you put

```
\show\TeX
```

into a LaTeX document it will stop and show on the terminal

```
> \TeX=macro:
 ->T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\@.
```

(The definition in plain TeX doesn't have the `\@`)

so if for some reason you don't want to type `\TeX` you can type

```
T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX\@
```

instead.

Comment: I see, and I assume

-.1667em\lower
.5ex\hbox

Modifies the height and position of the characters?

Comment: @user95869 the kerns are negative horizontal space and `\lower.5ex\hbox{E}` lowers the E, the trailing `\@` added by latex adjusts end of sentence space if a sentence ends `\TeX.`

Comment: +1, but missing the `T` in the last line of code.

Comment: @jon  oops :-)..