# How to set “LaTeX2e” in a document?

Tags: logos

There’s a question about [how to get “LaTeX” symbol in a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/how-to-get-latex-symbol-in-document), but the answer does not include LaTeX2e.
Searching for “LaTeX2e”, “LaTeX2e lettering” or “LaTeX2e writing” didn’t yield the answer, and neither did trying out the commands `\LaTeX2` and `\LaTeX2e`.

How to set LaTeX2e (and while we’re at it: LaTeX3) in a document?

Comment: You can use use `\LaTeXe` (too short to post it as answer). For LaTeX3 use `\LaTeX3`.

Comment: Amazing. I tried `\LaTeX2` and `\LaTeX2e` but didn’t think of `\LaTeXe`.

Comment: @TeXnician Since it is a valid answer you should.

Comment: @giusva Then I'll have to invent some text (as an answer needs some more characters) ;)

Comment: Here is an explanation of how it is defined: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80333/121944

Comment: also have a look at `metalogo` package

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to write (La)TeX (with parentheses) (or any other TeX-related logo)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11095/5764)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To typeset LaTeX2e use `\LaTeXe`. This is well documented in `source2e`:

> `\LaTeXe` The LaTeX2ε logo as proposed by A-W designers.

For LaTeX3 simply use `\LaTeX3`.

Comment: Maybe they should add the `lipsum` command for answer. :D