# Babel and hyperref prevent changes to the \LaTeX logo

Tags: hyperref, babel, logos

I once copied the definition of the \LaTeX command, put it as an argument to `\renewcommand{}{}` in order to tweak it to the font I was using. I've noticed that my redefinition has not had any effect for quite a while, and I've narrowed it down to it being due to *both* `babel` and `hyperref` being loaded.

In this MWE, I've changed [the original](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80335/9077) `\kern -.36em` to `\kern -.99em` so that the change would be clearly visible. With both `babel` and `hyperref` loaded, the `\LaTeX` logo appears unchanged:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern -.99em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

\LaTeX

\end{document}
```

[image]

With any of the two packages removed, this is the output:

[image]

My question is, how can I redefine the `\LaTeX` logo while at the same time load `babel` and `hyperref`?

Comment: Do you know about `metalogo`?

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is in lines 667–702 of `babel.sty`

```
    667 \bbl@trace{Encoding and fonts}
    668 \newcommand\BabelNonASCII{LGR,X2,OT2,OT3,OT6,LHE,LWN,LMA,LMC,LMS,LMU,PU,PD1}
    669 \newcommand\BabelNonText{TS1,T3,TS3}
    670 \let\org@TeX\TeX
    671 \let\org@LaTeX\LaTeX
    672 \let\ensureascii\@firstofone
    673 \AtBeginDocument{%
    674   \in@false
    675   \bbl@foreach\BabelNonASCII{% is there a text non-ascii enc?
    676     \ifin@\else
    677       \lowercase{\bbl@xin@{,#1enc.def,}{,\@filelist,}}%
    678     \fi}%
    679   \ifin@ % if a text non-ascii has been loaded
    680     \def\ensureascii#1{{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont#1}}%
    681     \DeclareTextCommandDefault{\TeX}{\org@TeX}%
    682     \DeclareTextCommandDefault{\LaTeX}{\org@LaTeX}%
    683     \def\bbl@tempb#1\@@{\uppercase{\bbl@tempc#1}ENC.DEF\@empty\@@}%
    684     \def\bbl@tempc#1ENC.DEF#2\@@{%
    685       \ifx\@empty#2\else
    686         \bbl@ifunset{T@#1}%
    687           {}%
    688           {\bbl@xin@{,#1,}{,\BabelNonASCII,\BabelNonText,}%
    689            \ifin@
    690              \DeclareTextCommand{\TeX}{#1}{\ensureascii{\org@TeX}}%
    691              \DeclareTextCommand{\LaTeX}{#1}{\ensureascii{\org@LaTeX}}%
    692            \else
    693              \def\ensureascii##1{{\fontencoding{#1}\selectfont##1}}%
    694            \fi}%
    695       \fi}%
    696     \bbl@foreach\@filelist{\bbl@tempb#1\@@}%  TODO - \@@ de mas??
    697     \bbl@xin@{,\cf@encoding,}{,\BabelNonASCII,\BabelNonText,}%
    698     \ifin@\else
    699       \edef\ensureascii#1{{%
    700         \noexpand\fontencoding{\cf@encoding}\noexpand\selectfont#1}}%
    701     \fi
    702   \fi}
```

which basically check, at begin document, whether some “strange” encoding has been loaded. In this case, `\LaTeX` (and `\TeX`, for what it's worth) is changed to be an encoding specific command, using as replacement text the meaning of `\LaTeX` valid when `babel.sty` has been loaded.

Why this is done is not difficult to understand: the LGR encoding has different glyphs in the standard ASCII positions and several others in the `\BabelNonASCII` list do as well. In this case, `hyperref` loads PU and PD1.

Solution: refresh also the meaning of `\org@LaTeX`. But probably there should be a different way to cope with this at the `babel` level, perhaps omitting `PU` and `PD1` from the list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern -.99em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX}
\let\org@LaTeX\LaTeX
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\LaTeX

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Addition

The issue should be solved with `babel` version 3.62

Comment: This part has been rewritten from scratch (see the following commit: https://github.com/latex3/babel/commit/4969492b424c57371cce33e10b2b941b40af405b ).

Answer (score 0):

hyperref and babel between them conspire to make this an encoding-specific command so one way is simply to define it (for `OT1` here) or for `T1` if you are using that, or `TU` for Unicode fonts in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \makeatletter

\DeclareTextCommand{\LaTeX}{OT1}{L\kern -.99em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX}
    \makeatother


\begin{document}


\LaTeX

\end{document}
```

Comment: no it is not hyperref's fault. babel detects at begin document that puenc.def has been loaded and then reverts the \LaTeX definition. No idea why it thinks that puenc is a "non-ascii encoding".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was going to check exactly why that was happening. Can I blame you anyway?

Comment: A simple `\g@addto@macro\@filelist{,puenc.def}` has the same effect, one doesn't need to load hyperref.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I changed the wording but suggested the same fix for now.

Comment: Actually, I'm using lualatex, loading a font with `fontspec`, so I assume this trick won't work? My MWE uses pdflatex, since I got the exact same result with pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex.

Comment: @Sverre It works in LuaLaTeX if you replace `{OT1}` with `{TU}`.

Comment: @Sverre I already say you might need T1, I'll add TU as well

Comment: `\encodingdefault`, perhaps?

Comment: @egreg I guess so, or see if babel can change, seems a bit weird to define an encoding-specific command that's the same in all real encodings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Try it with `LGR`

Comment: @egreg which suggests against using \encodingdefault

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that's true. I suggested it before actually looking at what's happening.