# List of agreed transliterations for TeX related logos for ebook publications?

Tags: latex-project, ebook, logos

Addison-Wesley is currently looking at providing an ebook version of *The LaTeX Companion* and while this is fairly simple if one provides it as a PDF document, any reflowable format, such as epub, poses some very difficult questions (and so far it is not clear if they can be resolved without losing too much in quality, although it looks more promising than I originally thought).

One issue is the question of handling the typical TeX-type logos and the first attempt to use fixed graphics turned out (not surprisingly) to be a total failure. Even in the right size they ended up rather distracting and in case of resizing the result was just horrible :-)

So one idea was simply use the typical transliterations, e.g., TeX, LaTeX, BibTeX, ... and in my opinion, while not perfect that may in fact be the best option within such formats.

So my question is is: is there anywhere a place that holds a fairly full list of typical transliterations used?

To clarify: what I'm looking for is a list of "ascii" renderings for all kind of TeX related names, I'm **not** looking for packages that implement logos for use within TeX.

Alan gave a good pointer in the comment "["Official" capitalizations of words from the TeX world](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/official-capitalizations-of-words-from-the-tex-world/2408)" but that one lacks a lot of logos still, Of the top of my head:

```
METAFONT    % just uppercase I guess
METAFUN     %
NTS         %

LaTeX2e     % LaTeX 2_epsilon (now here I know the source :-)

SliTeX      ???

PiCTeX      ???

eTeX        ??? no hyphen I think

MakeIndex    % logo normally just italics

TeXXeT       ???
exTeX        ???
```

Comment: i suggest just sticking with the ascii (or plain text) rendering, using the conventions practiced on the tug web site.  "transliterations" into ordinary alphabetical forms won't suffer from the glitches so often seen even in pdf renderings, which can be (and have been) used to knock tex's quality.  better to play it safe.

Comment: Duplicate of this meta question: ["Official" capitalizations of words from the TeX world](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2408) To the extent that it reflects some agreement here, it can be considered official. :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton maybe I didn't made myself clear: I'm looking for ascii renderings, and if possible for a really comprehensive list. For example, should it be AMS-TeX or AmSTeX or AMSTeX?

Comment: @AlanMunn perhaps a duplicate, but the answer there is missing a lot of names and is it really ture that it is AMS-TeX (just because that happens to be used on some website (even if by the AMS :-) ? I think AmSTeX is or was much more common

Comment: the AMS prefers AMS-TeX and AMS-LaTeX.  there has been a consensus here for a long time that the "lowered m" was a solution to a problem that didn't exist, and in fact caused more confusion than it avoided.  the representation in the list cited by @AlanMunn is valid in this respect.  (and sorry, i spaced right through the last sentence and the "transliterations" tag.  but it occurred to me, that if unicode can be used, then Ux0258, latin small letter reversed e, might be nice for the first e in XeTeX.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton nice idea about the reverted e but I guess I'll better stick with giving them ascii renderings (as I don't do the conversion myself, who knows what happens otherwise).

Comment: @FrankMittelbach While, with your angle, this question is definitely on-topic for the main site, we could as well just expand the list on meta? Then again, it might actually be better to keep the questions separate, since the meta question is intended to be a quick reference sort of thing, which doesn’t benefit from being bloated with lots of terms that are hardly ever used on the main site.

Comment: Related: [How to write (La)TeX (with parentheses) or any other TeX-related logo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11095/5764)

Comment: @Werner in a very vague sense but this question is asking for the opposite direction (one of the answers mentions hologo but that's about it)

Comment: Can we somehow make this question more discoverable on search engines? I just spent 30 minutes finding it because all my queries didn't work. "transliteration" really isn't the first thing that pops to a layman's mind when he tries to find something like the "lualatex logo command" or so.

Comment: These logos usually don't look good when you emphasize them and their definitions also depend on the type. I wrote special versions of them for my [_book_](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html). You may have a look at [this](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-1/tb91murzynowski-logo.pdf) note by Grzegorz Murzynowski, which inspired me to make the different versions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Package `hologo` supports `\hologo{<logo>}` inside `\csname`. This form generates an ASCII string:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\hologoEntry}[3]{%
  \ifx\\#2\\%
    \texttt{%
      \escapechar=-1 %
      \expandafter\string\csname\hologo{#1}\endcsname
    }&\hologo{#1}\tabularnewline
  \fi
}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \hologoList
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The used version of `hologo` is 2013/05/18 v1.14.
(Until it hits CTAN it is available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71873949/tex/hologo-1.14.pdf), the PDF file contains the DTX file as attachment. The command `tex hologo.dtx` extracts the package file.)

### SliTeX vs. SLiTeX

Sometime ago I had asked Leslie Lamport, from his reply:

> **SliTeX** (or **SLiTeX**) is long obsolete and I haven't looked at it in
>   years.  I see no reason why anyone would want to use the logo.

He suggests to use the "latest version", but that is a little undefined here.

### e-TeX vs. eTeX

- CTAN uses the hyphen: [CTAN:systems/**e-tex**/](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/)
- [README for v2.1](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2.1/README) uses `e-TeX` with hyphen:

> This directory contains the **e-TeX** V2.1 files.

- The [source for v2.1](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2.1/etex_src.zip) consists of `etex.ch` that uses `e-TeX` with hyphen:

> % This is etex.ch in text format, as of January 31, 1999.
>   % WEB change file containing code for various features extending TeX;
>   % to be applied to tex.web (Version 3.14159) in order to define the
>   % **e-TeX** program.
>
> % **e-TeX** is copyright (C) 1994,98 by the NTS team; all rights are reserved.
>   ...
>   % **e-TeX** and NTS are trademarks of the NTS group.
>   ...
>   @x limbo l.1 - this is **e-TeX**
>   ...

### ExTeX

In the [user's guide](http://www.extex.org/documentation/man/extex-users.pdf) I found:

> `# extex plain`
>   `This is`**`ExTeX`**

AFAIK the uppercase form for the ASCII form is used to avoid trouble with
uppercase contexts (start of sentence, ...).

Comment: That's a good source, thanks, but it isn't a decider for what the ascii rendering should be. Examples: AmS-TeX as Barbara tells us should be AMS-TeX because that is how the AMS wants it and is it now SLiTeX or SliTeX? or really e-TeX or eTeX?

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Thanks for the hint for `AMS`, I have taken it into account for `hologo` v1.14. I have updated my answer to add my remarks for the remaining questions about SLiTeX/SliTeX and e-TeX/eTeX.

Comment: list needs things like "Texmaker", "TeXShop" and "Textures".  facilities like these aren't always "uppercased" in the "expected" manner, even though they're usually not rendered with the (non-ascii) tex logo.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Many thanks, I will add them in the next version (1.15) in the form of simple ASCII strings.

Answer (score 6):

I know this doesn't answer the question of translit, but if I've understood correctly, ePub is just CSS and HTML and whatnot. So a feed to [fontsquirrel's generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) for [Latin Modern Roman](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern), and out pops woffs and eots and whatnot. So:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>style</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <style>
    @font-face { font-family: 'LMR'; src: local('Latin Modern Roman') }
    body { font-size: 600% }
    abbr { font-family: 'LMR'; position: relative }
    abbr .texe {
      position: relative;
      margin-left: -.1667em;
      bottom: -.5ex;
      margin-right: -.125em }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <abbr>Τ<span class="texe">Ε</span>Χ</abbr>
</body>
</html>
```

Looks like

[image]

Yeeeah, I took it a bit too far there, didn't I.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'm not sure it is practical in my case (if you can't really control what happens in the production cycle) and it would probably need to be adjusted to the fonts used. Still might be worth collecting for the main TeX logos in case some TeX docs are transfered to epub or some other ebook format.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Also package `hologo` tries to support HTML (TeX4ht). But quite a few logos make trouble because of special font and glyph requirements.

Comment: It's also nice to set the `E` in the markup as a lowercase `e` and doing a `text-transform: uppercase` in CSS. That way, users that suppress styles in HTML documents see `TeX`, whereas others still will see the logo typeset the way you show.