# How to write LaTeX as title in acm format?

Tags: titles, acm

I wrote Latex as `\LaTeX` to properly make the right output on the title part using `acm_proc_article-sp` document class. But as I wrote that way, it prints a very small letter 'A' of the LATEX word.

[image]

I think it wasn't right for the 'A' gets anussual result. Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: That is considered to be the default output for `\LaTeX`. Compare this against others contained in [How to write (La)TeX (with parentheses) or any other TeX-related logo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11095/5764). Moreover, [`acm_proc_article-sp.cls`](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/acm_proc_article-sp.cls) does not redefine `\LaTeX` in any way.

Comment: Write `\LaTeX` in a common class like `article`. The result is the same. This is the correct format for the logo.

Comment: the required format for our documentation is in acm. so im using the 'acm_proc_article-sp.cls'

Comment: @joya, I know. What I meant was that the problem is not specific to the class `acm_proc_article-sp`, because the same little A is obtained with all standard classes. In fact, this is not a problem at all. It should be smaller. It would be funny if LaTeX did not know how properly format your own logo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The class `acm_proc_article_sp` uses a ***wrong*** way to select fonts. The title is typeset with

```
\ttlfont <title text>
```

where `\ttlfont` is defined at line `320` in the `.cls` file by

```
\newfont{\ttlfnt}{phvb8t at 18pt}
```

The `\newfont` command in LaTeX has been deprecated since LaTeX2<sub>ε</sub> has been released, eighteen years ago.

You can fix this by changing the way fonts are defined:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\newcommand{\fixnewfont}[6]{%
  % #1 = name, #2 = family, #3 = weight,
  % #4 = shape, #5 = size, #6 = baselineskip
  \renewcommand#1{\fontsize{#5}{#6}\usefont{\encodingdefault}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}

\fixnewfont{\secfnt}{ptm}{b}{n}{12}{14}
\fixnewfont{\secit}{ptm}{b}{it}{12}{14}
\fixnewfont{\subsecfnt}{ptm}{m}{it}{11}{14}
\fixnewfont{\subsecit}{ptm}{b}{it}{11}{14}
\fixnewfont{\ttlfnt}{phv}{b}{n}{18}{20}
\fixnewfont{\ttlit}{phv}{b}{sl}{18}{20}
\fixnewfont{\subttlfnt}{phv}{m}{n}{14}{20}
\fixnewfont{\subttlit}{phv}{m}{sl}{14}{20}
\fixnewfont{\subttlbf}{phv}{b}{n}{14}{20}
\fixnewfont{\aufnt}{phv}{m}{n}{12}{16}
\fixnewfont{\auit}{phv}{m}{sl}{12}{16}
\fixnewfont{\affaddr}{phv}{m}{n}{10}{12}
\fixnewfont{\affaddrit}{phv}{m}{sl}{10}{12}
\fixnewfont{\eaddfnt}{phv}{m}{n}{12}{14}
\fixnewfont{\ixpt}{ptm}{m}{n}{9}{11}
\fixnewfont{\confname}{ptm}{m}{it}{8}{10}
\fixnewfont{\crnotice}{ptm}{m}{n}{8}{10}
\fixnewfont{\ninept}{ptm}{m}{n}{9}{10.5}


\begin{document}
\title{\LaTeX{} is nice}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use such a class for any other purpose than submissions that require it.

Comment: I included the solution you had given me to redefine the font in the actual class and it was the corrected to what should it be. Thank you!

Comment: Can you relate this answer to specific versions of the document class?