# Math in paper title is wrong size (too small)

Tags: titles, fontsize

The title of my paper contains a math mode expression. Usually this renders correctly, but with the style file I am using for the proceedings in which it will appear, the math mode part appears in normal-size font while the rest of the title is title-size, making the math part look very small. This also happens in section headings.

The style file is here: www.sheridanprinting.com/typedept/sig-alternate-2013.cls

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-2013}
\begin{document}
\title{Proving that $1 > 0$}
\maketitle
\section{Proving that $1 > 0$}
\end{document}
```

Any advice as to how to to fix this would be great, thank you.

Comment: Same basic problem as [How to write LaTeX as title in acm format?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125830/how-to-write-latex-as-title-in-acm-format) -- this class uses font commands that were deprecated 20 years ago. @egreg's corrections in the other post get the math much closer to the title font, but the change between the Helvetica text font and the Computer Modern math font is still pretty jarring.

Comment: @MikeRenfro, thanks, perhaps just post that as an answer so I can accept it? (or close as duplicate) It is jarring but better than nothing.

Comment: Voting to close, then. Adding the [sansmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/sansmath) package helps a bit, but not enough.