# Using tikz package in LaTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I have difficulty in the use of tikz package. I want to be like the output below. Please heip me! Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: It seems to be much more than `minipage`. Maybe you should look around for a calss.

Comment: Please do NOT edit your question to include an answer - especially not an answer you've just copied from one of the answers to your original question. Doing so makes the existing answers make no sense and doing so without even bothering to attribute the code to its author is extremely rude when people have spent a good deal of time to help you despite your apparently making no effort to help yourself before or after asking your question.

Comment: Take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324218/1952

Answer (score 7):

First of all, read tutorial 1 in `pgfmanual`. After that you will understand how to draw this simple graphic.

Second, take a look at `tcolorbox` documentation and you'll see how to format this kind of boxes.

After that, try to understand following code and you'll be able to adapt it to your needs:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{boxone}{%
    enhanced,
    colback=brown!10,
    boxrule=0pt,
    sharp corners,
    frame hidden,
    fontupper=\bfseries,
    notitle,
    overlay={%
        \draw[Circle-Circle, brown!70!black, line width=2pt](frame.north west)--(frame.south west); 
        \draw[Circle-Circle, brown!70!black, line width=2pt](frame.north east)--(frame.south east);}
    }

\newtcolorbox{boxtwo}{%
    enhanced,
    %frame style={draw=none},
    colback=orange!20,
    boxrule=0pt,
    sharp corners,
    frame hidden,
    notitle,
    overlay={%
        \draw[{Triangle[right]}-{Triangle[left]}, , line width=2pt](frame.north west)--(frame.north east); 
        \draw[{Triangle[left]}-{Triangle[right]}, , line width=2pt](frame.south west)--(frame.south east);}
    }

\newtcolorbox{boxthree}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    %frame style={draw=none},
    colback=orange!10,
    colbacktitle=orange!10,
    boxrule=0pt,
    fonttitle=\Large\bfseries,
    coltitle=brown!30!black,
    sharp corners,
    frame hidden,
    title=#2,
    overlay={%
        \draw[thick, brown!70!black, double=orange, double distance=2pt] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east); 
        \draw[thick, brown!70!black, double=orange, double distance=2pt] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
        \fill[red!50!brown] ([shift={(3mm,.5mm)}]title.south west)--([shift={(-3mm,0mm)}]title.south east)--([shift={(3mm,-.5mm)}]title.south west)--cycle;}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{boxone}
\lipsum[1]
\end{boxone}

\begin{boxtwo}
\lipsum[3]
\end{boxtwo}

\begin{boxthree}{Nice maths}
\[\sin^2 x + \cos^2 = 1\]
\end{boxthree}

{\par\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, dotted] (0,0) grid (7,4);
\draw[cyan] (1,1) node[below left, black] {$B$}--node[above left]{$c$} (2,3) node[above, black]{$A$}--node[above right]{$b$} (6,1) node[below right, black]{$C$}--node[below]{$c'$}(2,1) node[below,black]{$H$}--node[below]{$b'$}(1,1)--cycle;
\draw[violet] (2,1)--node[right]{$h$}(2,3);
\draw[violet] (2,1.2)-|(2.2,1);
\draw[thin] (1,.9)--++(-90:.8) (6,.9)--++(-90:.8);
\draw[LaTeX-LaTeX] (1,.3)-- node[fill=white]{$a$}(6,.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The above code generates the error:

''pgfkeys Erros:I do not know the key '/tcb/shap corners',...''

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: @tranhoang150488 You probably have an old tcolorbox version. Update it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, how to get “LaTeX” symbol in document{book}??

Comment: @tranhoang150488 This is another question, but ... `\LaTeX` or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-parentheses-or-any-other-tex-related-logo

Comment: How to change the length and width of text box above?Please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: @tranhoang150488 -- Look at the option `twocolumn` in the `\documentclass`. Is that the culprit? Or do you mean: I intend to make my boxes have different widths, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You do not show what have tried. But have a look at the following code. It will give you a possible starting point.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tcolorbox,tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \y in {1,...,34} {
\begin{tcolorbox}
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
This is another \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title= My nice title]
\foreach \z in {1,...,10} {This is a long \textbf{tcolorbox}.}
\end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]