# What is the font used by \LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

I want to create a greetings card written in the same font as the \LaTeX macro (i.e.
[image]).

However, for obvious reasons, it's immensely difficult to create a Google query which gives me the answer.
Does anyone know the font used in the [image] macro?

To be clear: I want to create text similar to the LaTeX logo:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/LaTeX_logo.svg

but I want to write something other than "LaTeX". Is this possible?

Comment: Unless you're asking how `\LaTeX` is defined – for that, `$ texdef -t latex LaTeX` :-)

Comment: it uses the font current at that point in the document. compare `\LaTeX, \textbf{\LaTeX}, \textsf{\LaTeX}`

Comment: Yes; for instance, what does `\sffamily\LaTeX` look like? What about `\sffamily\itshape\LaTeX`?

Comment: It doesn't usually change shape just for the E, though, which your example does.

Comment: I don't quite follow. If I write "This is some font.
\LaTeX $\leftarrow$ That is a different font, though. Right?" I get https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxpo6ofns5pummo/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede%202017-02-05%2021.04.12.png?dl=0. They're not the same font. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Oh! I get it! It's the same font, but some of the letters are lowered/raised! I'll edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11096/36296 for how to lower/raise the letters