# Is there a \LuaTeX symbol?

Tags: symbols, luatex

I could use a `\LaTeX` and `\XeTeX` with package `xltxtra`, but I could not found a way to write `LuaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Have a look at the `hologo` package.

Comment: Just use `Lua\TeX` and `Lua\LaTeX`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-parentheses-or-any-other-tex-related-logo/67990#67990

Comment: So, the answer is NO.

Comment: @Wentao The answer is YES as provided by egreg. Or if you insist on a complete macro: `newcommand*{\LuaLaTex}{Lua\LaTeX}`

Comment: No, the answer is yes. `hologo` (as mentioned above) has logos for LuaTeX/LuaLaTeX (`\hologo{LuaTeX}\hologo{LuaLaTeX}`), they just weren't explicitly mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67990/. Further, the accepted answer to that question isn't up to date `dtk-logos` provides `\luatex`/`\LuaTeX` and `\lualatex`/`\LualaTeX`, though the packages use `hologo` in the definition.

Comment: Okay. Not exactly what I expected, but fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the *exact same* logo as the one in the LuaTeX manual, you can copy the definition from the ConTeXt core file [`cont-log.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/d3ddabbb5b5f45bac3da8cb51d3e63810aa2d4ca/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-log.mkiv#L274-L296).

It is only marginally different from `Lua\TeX`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\unexpanded\protected
\let\dontleavehmode\leavevmode
\newdimen\zeropoint \zeropoint=0pt

% from cont-log.mkiv
\unexpanded\def\LuaTeX
  {\dontleavehmode
   \begingroup
     Lua%
     % hope for kerning, try aT
     \setbox0\hbox{aT}%
     \setbox2\hbox{a\kern\zeropoint T}%
     \ifdim\wd0=\wd2 % kerns can go two ways
       % no aT kerning, try oT as a is not symmetrical
       \setbox0\hbox{oT}%
       \setbox2\hbox{o\kern\zeropoint T}%
       \ifdim\wd0=\wd2 % kerns can go two ways
         % no aT and oT kerning, try To
         \setbox0\hbox{To}%
         \setbox2\hbox{T\kern\zeropoint o}%
         % maybe we need to compensate for the angle (sl/it/bs/bi)
       \fi
       \ifdim\wd0=\wd2\else
         \kern\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
       \fi
     \fi
     \TeX
   \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\LuaTeX

Lua\TeX

\end{document}
```

[image]